Stripe PaymentMethod API giving a error during api creation
Here is my code for Create a PaymentMethod API . I found this code from
https://docs.stripe.com/api/payment_methods/create
But it is giving error . need a solution for overcome this issue.
Here is the guideline for pci-compliant : .setPaymentMethod("pm_card_visa")


import com.stripe.Stripe;
import com.stripe.exception.StripeException;
import com.stripe.model.PaymentMethod;
import com.stripe.param.PaymentMethodCreateParams;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws StripeException {

        System.out.println("Hello world!");
        Stripe.apiKey = "sk_t";
        PaymentMethodCreateParams params =
                PaymentMethodCreateParams.builder()
                        .setType(PaymentMethodCreateParams.Type.CARD)
                        .setCard(
                                PaymentMethodCreateParams.CardDetails.builder()
                                        .setNumber("pm_card_visa")
                                        .setExpMonth(8L)
                                        .setExpYear(2026L)
                                        .setCvc("314")
                                        .build()
                        )
                        .build();
        PaymentMethod paymentMethod = PaymentMethod.create(params);
        System.out.println("done!");
    }
}

I have found bellow error after running this code . please help why it is giving this error.
I am using this stripe version : 25.0.0
Error :
**Sending credit card numbers directly to the Stripe API is generally unsafe. We suggest you use test tokens that map to the test card you are using, see https://stripe.com/docs/testing. To enable raw card data APIs in
**
Exception in thread "main" com.stripe.exception.CardException: 
Sending credit card numbers directly to the Stripe API is generally unsafe. We suggest you use test tokens that map to the test card you are using, see https://stripe.com/docs/testing. To enable raw card data APIs in test mode, see https://support.stripe.com/questions/enabling-access-to-raw-card-data-apis.; request-id: req_UzVH4M3J5n22oP
    at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.handleApiError(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:255)
    at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.handleError(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:198)
    at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.request(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:102)
    at com.stripe.model.PaymentMethod.create(PaymentMethod.java:405)
    at com.stripe.model.PaymentMethod.create(PaymentMethod.java:379)
    at com.sam.Main.main(Main.java:32)


Process finished with exit code 1

As per the link in the error message, you shouldn't be (and can't, by default) send raw card data directly to the API.
Instead, you should be collecting payment information from your customers using Stripe's PCI compliant UIs, such as Payment Element or Checkout which automatically handle the tokenisation and creation of the Payment Method object (pm_xxx).
I'd recommend starting with this guide, which is an end-to-end example of accepting payments using Elements.

As per stripe guideline  , When writing test code, use a PaymentMethod such as pm_card_visa instead of a card number.  it is already PCI-compliant . SO, it is giving issue. if use 4242424242424242 so it is not pic standard.

My understanding is : I am already using pci compilant coding  setNumber("pm_card_visa")              is  PCI-compliant
setNumber("4242424242424242 ")         is not PCI-compliant

The test cards you're using is irrelevant. Your integration overall is not PCI compliant and without the necessary PCI compliance certification, you cannot pass card data directly to the API that way.
